# Setting a style on an XWPFRun by style ID

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to apply named styles to individual runs in an XWPFDocument, and I am seeing strange results.

The [javadoc for XWPFRun describes the setStyle method](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#setStyle-java.lang.String-), but the style *appears* to not be applied in the final document. I say *appears*, because in the QuickLook preview in Finder, the style *does* appear on the run as expected. In the example below, I am applying a named style to the hyperlink, which appears as expected in the preview on the right, but not in Word on the left.

[image]

So clearly POI is actually doing something to apply the style, but Word is not rendering the style. I tried several other .docx readers, all of which produced similar results.

So I started peeling apart the style and applying the attributes to the run individually, which *does* work in Word. This is one of those things that seems like I must just be missing something. I *can* of course write a routine that can read in an existing style and apply it to a run like this, but I would much rather not. I have searched for answers, but this part of POI seems to be very much a work in progress.

So am I just missing something obvious, or am I going to just have to suck it up and do this the painful way?

```
//This does not work.
run.setStyle(styleId);

if(docStyles.styleExist(styleId))
{

    /*
        In order to set the style on the run, we need to manually
        determine the properties of the style, and set them on the
        run individually.

        This makes no sense.
     */
    XWPFStyle style = docStyles.getStyle(styleId);

    CTStyle ctStyle = style.getCTStyle();
    CTRPr ctRpr = ctStyle.getRPr();

    if (ctRpr.isSetB())
    {
        CTOnOff onOff = ctRpr.getB();
        STOnOff.Enum stOnOff = onOff.getVal();

        boolean bold = (stOnOff == STOnOff.TRUE);

        run.setBold(bold);
    }
    if(ctRpr.isSetU())
    {
        CTUnderline underline = ctRpr.getU();
        STUnderline.Enum val = underline.getVal();

        UnderlinePatterns underlinePattern = UnderlinePatterns.valueOf(val.intValue());

        run.setUnderline(underlinePattern);
    }
    // ... //
}
else
{
    System.out.println("404: Style not found");
}
```

Comment: How is this `XWPFDocument` created? From scratch using `apache poi` and the `XWPFStyles` using `XWPFDocument.createStyles()`?  If  so pĺease show the code part which is doing this and also how the named `XWPFStyle` comes into the `XWPFStyles`. Or is the `XWPFDocument` created from a template which contains the named style already? If so please do providing the template for downloading somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `XWPfDocument` is created from a template, then this template must contain the named style "Hyperlink" already. That means, it must contain in `/word/styles.xml` the entry in latent styles

```
...
<w:latentStyles...
...
 <w:lsdException w:name="Hyperlink" w:qFormat="1"/>
...
```

as well as the style definition

```
...
<w:style w:type="character" w:styleId="Hyperlink">
 <w:name w:val="Hyperlink"/>
 <w:basedOn w:val="..."/>
 <w:uiPriority w:val="99"/>
 <w:unhideWhenUsed/>
 <w:qFormat/>
 <w:rsid w:val="00072FE4"/>
 <w:rPr>
  <w:color w:val="0000FF" w:themeColor="hyperlink"/>
  <w:u w:val="single"/>
 </w:rPr>
</w:style>
...
```

If that is true then the following code works for me using `apache poi 4.0.0`:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHyperlink;

public class CreateWordStyledHyperlinkRunFromTemplate {

 static XWPFHyperlinkRun createHyperlinkRun(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String uri) throws Exception {
  String rId = paragraph.getPart().getPackagePart().addExternalRelationship(
    uri, 
    XWPFRelation.HYPERLINK.getRelation()
   ).getId();

  CTHyperlink cthyperLink=paragraph.getCTP().addNewHyperlink();
  cthyperLink.setId(rId);
  cthyperLink.addNewR();

  return new XWPFHyperlinkRun(
    cthyperLink,
    cthyperLink.getRArray(0),
    paragraph
   );
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("Template.docx"));

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("This is a text paragraph having a link to Google ");

  XWPFHyperlinkRun hyperlinkrun = createHyperlinkRun(paragraph, "https://www.google.de");
  hyperlinkrun.setText("https://www.google.de");
  XWPFStyles styles = document.getStyles();
  if (styles.styleExist("Hyperlink")) {
   System.out.println("Style Hyperlink exists."); //Template must contain named style "Hyperlink" already
   hyperlinkrun.setStyle("Hyperlink");
  } else {
   hyperlinkrun.setColor("0000FF");
   hyperlinkrun.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.SINGLE);
  }

  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText(" in it.");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordStyledHyperlinkRunFromTemplate.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Note there is not any possibility for creating [XWPFHyperlinkRun](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFHyperlinkRun.html) except using the low level `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHyperlink` class.

It produces:

[image]

Comment: It turns out the style defined in the template file was a "Paragraph" style, not a "Character" style, which was causing it not to be rendered on the run. Redefining the template style produced the expected results.

My code looks pretty much like yours, but when you posted the style definition, I noticed the difference in the style type. Thanks!